# Storage in embedded linux

Tags: embedded, linux, beagleboard

I am basically from a background of small microcontrollers(arm7,cortex-m series). As I started working with a cortex a8 board(beagleboard xm), I always wonder how to store applications in flash/ram memory. In small controllers, you will directly give the location(which you know either flash or ram), but whensoever I store an application /home/root which memory is it stored?

Basically where the rootfile system is located in memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As is the same with Linux on full-size machines, the bootloader passes the location of the root as the `root` argument to the kernel. The bootloader itself (usually Das u-Boot) is responsible for checking NOR flash, NAND flash, SD, USB, SATA, PXE, etc. to see if a kernel and optional initrd can be found, and passing options as defined in the board's environment variables.

TL;DR: Check the bootloader configuration and kernel command line.

Comment: As the person above says where the root filesystem is loaded should be defined in the bootloader. Why do you need to know this exactly? If you just want to transfer a file to the rhs that's a different story, and is quite easy.